# How to disable user interaction for MGLAnnotation?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapbox, mglmapview

I am using mapbox and have a post made up of 2 annotations. One can and another cannot (should not) be selectable.

**How can I make a specific MGLAnnotation unselectable?**

I have looked [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10539) and [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/11234) and did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution is very simple inside of the `class Custom2DotAnnotation: MGLAnnotationView {`
just add `self.isEnabled = false`